# Discrete Logarithm within DH exchange - finding out A and B secret number

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

How would i find out Alices or Bobs private number from the details exchanged in public.

prime - g = 7

primitive root - n = 3

Alice - A = 3

Bob - B = 4

The details visible in public exchange are:

g = 7

n = 3

Ya == 27 mod 7

Yb == 81 mod 7

How would one go about finding Alices secret number A or Bobs secret number B from the exchange usings only the visible details exchanged in public space. Please provide an explanation to notation as well as a practice solution to the scenario I've provided.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. What have you tried? Normally, Alice sends $n^A$, Bob sends $n^B$, use discrete log or even better use brute force, the prime is just 7. **Note :** standard notation: $p=7$, $g=4$ Alice sends $g^a$, Bob sends $g^b$. $\{3,2,6,4,5,1\}, g^i$'s.

Comment: my approach from what i read should be **A = DLOGn,g(Ya)** and **B = DLOGn,g(Yb)**, however i fail to understand how to implement this notation to discover A or B.

Comment: $27 = 6 \mod 7$ and that is in the which elt in the $g^i$'s list?